# datatime.datatime.strptime to extract date

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime-format, strptime, python-3.6

I am getting towards the end of this project and I am stuck again. So far the programs goes to the usgs site from a url to extract specific data, I have gotten it to seperate the data and metadata know I need to do something else but

I'm not sure what or how, the data that I have populated is 1500 line here are a few

```
USGS    14211720    2017-01-30 19:15    PST 28600   P   6.26    P
USGS    14211720    2017-01-30 19:30    PST 30400   P   6.17    P
USGS    14211720    2017-01-30 19:45    PST 38300   P   6.03    P
source   site #       date                discharge     stage level
```

the partial code I was given with the instructions is

```
import datetime

# define empty lists, we will append the data to them
dateList = []
dischargeList = []
stagelevelList = []

for line in dataLines:
    # use 'datatime.datatime.strptime()' to extract date
    #use the '.strip()' and float() functions to convert values
    print (dateList)    
    print("we have {} items in the date list".format(len(dateList)))
    print("we have {} items in the discharge list".format(len(dischargeList)))
    print("we have {} items in the velocity list".format(len(stagelevelList)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from the code comments that you are expected to convert the date from a string to a `datetime` object which is done with `datetime.datetime.strptime`.  If you look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), you will see that this conversion uses a special set of format codes to specify how the string is constructed.  For your string you would use

```
import datetime

date_str = "2017-01-30 19:15"
date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

From the datetime object, you can convert the date into a string with any format you desire.

```
print(date_obj.strftime("%A %B %d at %H:%M in %Y"))
# Monday January 30 at 19:15 in 2017
```

Comment: So I have added the date_obj line, and added a dateList .append(line) and I the a date_str not defined  and the dateList is empty, I need to fill all three of the defined files or what ever they are called with the data from the 1400 line list but I need to only put specific columns in each